# MATLAB 2014b fminunc provide gradient

Tags: matlab, minimization

How can I provide the gradient of the function when using the unconstrained minimization solver `fminunc` as the following options provided in the online documentation of the solver 
`options = optimoptions('fminunc','Algorithm','trustregion','SpecifyObjectiveGradient',true);`
is not available in MATLAB 2014b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GradObj` option. For example, say we have the function x1^2+x2^4:

```
function  [f,g]= goal(x)
    f= x(1)^2+x(2)^4;   % function
    if nargout>1    % gradient
        g= [2*x(1);4*x(2)^3];
    end
end
```

We need to set `GradObj` option:

```
options=optimset('GradObj','on');
```

Now we can obtain the solution:

```
x= fminunc(@goal,x0,options) % x0 is the inital point
```